# error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: windows, python, sockets

I am creating system tests on a Windows7 machine using python, in which I need to open various socket connections to other machines. I also have several virtual IPs added to the local machine.

These tests sometimes work, but when executed quickly after each other, I always run into the following error:

```
error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

This problem has been posted a couple of time, but no answer seems to solve the problem on my computer. Here are some more specific information:

- Each socket created in python has the following option set:

  ```
  setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  ```
- I also changed `regedit` entries following the hints to [avoiding ports exhaustion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610%28v=bts.20%29.aspx), which does not fix my problem. `netstat -n` only shows about max. 30 ports in state 'ESTABLISHED' or 'TIME_WAIT' up to port number 10000.
- As far as I can tell from the code, the connections are all closed. But even if they aren't, I need the connections to be closed or to be reused immediately.

How can I fix this problem to avoid this error?

Current code implementation:

```
def my_connect(self):
    if self._socket:
        self._socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self._socket.close()
    self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self._socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    self._socket.bind((self._bind_address, self._bind_port))
    self._socket.connect(self._address)
    return
```

Comment: are you calling socket.Shutdown() on the port before reusing? I doubt that you are hitting exhaustion, but more that you are trying to use a socket that is in an inappropriate state for your operation (for instance creating a new socket on that port while the old one hasn't closed yet. )

Comment: @Frank: It seem to fix my problem when I call `socket.shutdown()` just before closing the connection. Or should I call `socket.shutdown()` better just before I am to create a new socket connection?

Comment: Also now I get a different error when calling `shutdown`: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Comment: I just realized your suggestion does not work. I still get the original error again.

Comment: Don't just run shutdown blindly, be sure to check your socket status, and only Close() or Shutdown() the socket if it is open. see some details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185165/query-socket-connection-state-in-python

Comment: you may also have to wait a few milliseconds between ending the connection and closing the socket. network operations are always asynchronous, because the OS is whats doing the work, and because an established connection still needs to pass a few packets to FIN appropriately.

Comment: How to adjust the given code example to make re-connections onto the same address/port possible without running into an error?